# How to create magento theme from scratch in 1.9.1

Tags: magento, themes

Whether i have to copy the templates files from default or rwd package to create new theme from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

No need to copy the templates files or layout files unless you have your custom. System will find the template file/layout file from base package or default theme once no existence in your theme.